# How can I push data from Informix to .NET server in real time?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr, informix

I need to push data from Informix to my .NET server in real time, just like we can do it automatically as soon as there is a change in the database with SignalR and MS SQL Server. Can this be done? Informix doesn't seem to have inbuilt functionality that would allow .NET server to know whenever there is a new record in the database. I have not been able to find a solution to this even after hours and hours of searching with Google.

Answer (score 0):

Since Informix 11.70, Informix has supported a Change Data Capture API.  You can find links to this on Google with 'informix change data capture', but you do need to know that the qualifying term to use is 'change data capture'.  Some other DBMS also use the term 'change data capture' for basically the same functionality.

Links on IBM's site include:

- [What's new in Informix 11.70](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.cdc.doc/ids_cdc_067.htm)
- [The Change Data Capture API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.cdc.doc/ids_cdc_067.htm)

Other links include:

- [IBM Informix Change Data Capture API](http://www.oninit.com/manual/informix/117/documentation/ids_cdc_bookmap.pdf)
- [IBM Informix Change Data Capture API](https://www.cursor-distribution.de/aktuell.11.70.xC8/documentation/ids_cdc_bookmap.pdf)

These seem to be more or less the same manual, and an IBM-provided manual; it is almost certainly available on the IBM site to.